# Как выводить 3 новости на главной странице и динамически генерировать ссылку для остальных?

Tags: html, python, cgi

Подскажите есть ли готовый алгоритм, по следующей задаче, а то сам пока стопорнулся на переборе в цикле `while` списка из статей полученных методом `os.listdir("/news")` не пойму как полученные в цикле значения подставить в качестве страниц.
Есть папка с новостями (`/news`), в этой папке `html` страницы (`1.html`, `2.html` и т.д.).
Главная (`index.cgi`) представляет из себя `cgi python` скрипт. C содержанием вида:

```
print """
........
<div id="news1"> %s </div>
<div id="news2"> %s</div>
<div id="news3> %s </div>
<div id="nav_news"> %s </div>
.........
""" % (last_news, last_news-1, last_news-2, links)
```

Необходимо на главной выводить последние три новости из папки (скажем если новостей 8, то первой новостью содержимое страницы `8.html`, второй новостью содержимое страницы `7.html`, 3-й новостью содержимое страницы `6.html`). Далее генерировать ссылку на вторую страницу (для блока `div` c `id="nav_news"`) и уже на второй странице размещать новости с файлов `5.html`, `4.html`, `3.html`. Далее генерировать ссылку на третью страницу и на ней размещать новости в блоках `div` c `id="news1"` и `news2` - `2.html` и `1.html` соответсвенно. И так далее генерировать ссылки в зависимости от того сколько в папке новостей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cgi, os

def generatelinks(page):
    htmls = os.listdir("/news")
    htmls.reverse()
    pages = htmls[(page-1)*3:(page-1)*3+3]
    while len(pages)<3:
        pages.append("")
    print """
        ........
        <div id="news1"> %s </div>
        <div id="news2"> %s </div>
        <div id="news3"> %s </div>
        <div id="nav_news"><a href="http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/index.py?page=%s"> Next page </a></div>
        ........
        """ % (pages[0], pages[1], pages[2], page+1)

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
page = form.getvalue("page", "1")
page = int(page)
generatelinks(page)
```

Comment: @dinar-gataulin, </html> """.format(*pages, page+1)) 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
на сервере python 2.7.9

Comment: Изменил распаковку списка. Проверь сейчас.

Comment: @dinar-gatulin, тоже самое SyntaxError: invalid syntax
хотя... сейчас пробовал с другова компа там просто в разделах новостей {0}  блоке news2 идет {1}...Хотя я уже успел на сервере к первоначальному виду вернуть... странно как-то

Comment: а. ну это потому что остались ссылки на .format(

Comment: Исправил форматирование, проверил на 2.7 - работает

Comment: @dinar-gatulin, Вот спасибо большое! Работает, но только не выводит содержимое страницы, а печатает её название... пробовал делать `<?php include %s ?>` но почему-то не подгружает. Кроме как считывать содержимое методом `pages[0].read()` есть еще варианты? И еще я не  доконца понимаю происходящее тут, касательно переменной `page`. Она же нигде не задается. Ну то есть, чтобы получить её из `form.getvalue("page", 1)`, её надо было передать из формы или еще как, но нигде же не передается

Comment: в общем использовать include плохая идея, так как он запрещен в большинстве случаев. На помощь пришел jquery. C учетом этого код не много изменился и стал выглядеть так: 
блоки div `<div id="news1"> <script> $("#news1").load("%s"); </script> 
</div>` и 
.... `</html> """  % ("news/"+pages[0], "news/"+pages[1], "news/"+pages[2], page+1)`

и тут отсортируем список, так как может выдаваться в случайном порядке `htmls = sorted(os.listdir("news"))`